# File owner/group 48/48

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm having a problem. In my PHP host when I create a file or dir (via `rename()` or `mkdir()`) my files are created with OWNER 48, GROUP 48, instead of FTP OWNER/GROUP (like other hosts).

The problem is that if I do a `mkdir()` for instance, via PHP, I can't manager this dir (like put some files in, rename dir or remove), even in PHP! If I create this dir via FTP I can do all. Really strange.

Now I need know: I'm wrong or my PHP Host is bugged? They told me that it's a code problem.

My code:

```
mkdir($image_dir, 0777, true);
```

It'll create on FTP something like that:

```
NAME   TYPE  DATE   PERMS      OWNER/GROUP
./1967 [DIR] [DATE] fle (0755) 48/48
```

Even I set chmod on `mkdir()` to 0777, it create like 0755.

So, I can do something, or my host need does?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to `chown` the files back to your ftp user/group?

Comment: What output do you get if you run a PHP script with `<?php echo "UID = " . getmyuid() . ", User = " . get_current_user(); ?>`  PHP is probably running as a different user than your FTP user.

Comment: I get the FTP owner ID, 10062. And yes, it's the problem. Maybe can be related to SAFE_MODE? I read in other post.

Comment: btw you can not chown files to another user if you're not root. this would be a security risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at first this is not strange, it's good that webserver/php are running as a different user than your ftp client.

well this is ugly but may help you: in php use `umask(0000);` before any file operations. it will try to make all files and directories `0777` when created by php.

you should check if webserver/php and ftp client are at least in the same group so you can use the umask 0007.

btw. does php run in safe mode? it could prevent making files writable to other users... anyway you  should be sure to disable it as it's deprecated since php 5.3 and removed since 5.4

Comment: Yeah... I think that it is the problem, the `safe_mode`. I noted now that it is enabled on server. I send a ticket to host to disable it. Thanks. But I'll try your method.

Comment: Cool!!! Even with `safe_mode` enabled it works perfectly. The file is created with owner 48, but PHP can work on this dir normally. Thanks!

Comment: I'm actually thinking his problem was more because the default permission was set to enable the "Sticky bit". (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/02/sticky-bit-on-directory-file/)