# AWS EC2 vsftpd shows file/directory owner as number (48)

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, file-io, vsftpd

question:

I'm just getting into aws. I've installed vsftpd on my instance, set up usergroups and all that jazz. It works really well, except I've noticed that the owner on all the files are numbered. The owner isn't the user that that it should be.

What I'm trying to do is a mkdir with php, which works fine:

```
<?php
mkdir('test', 0777);
?>
```

But the owner shows up as '48'.
It should be the owner of the domain correct? 48 is not the owner. 
safe_mode is turned off.

When doing a 'ls -l' in the directory from the command line, the owner and group are both what they should be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File owner/group 48/48](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020683/file-owner-group-48-48)

Comment: Sorry no. Safe_mode is already turned off, and everything works as expected. I'm trying to figure out why the client would show a numbered owner, when the command line shows the proper owner

Comment: Which OS do you use on aws?

Comment: Not sure. It's an Amazon AMI that I've just changed a bit. running uname -a gives me this:
Linux domU-12-31-39-12-7D-E9 3.2.38-5.48.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Feb 13 01:07:25 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

48 maybe group/owner id. Type `cat /etc/passwd` in terminal to make sure.

**Note:** When you create files or directory from php/wsgi app/etc, your webserver user and group (e.g. www-data for apache2 on debian) become owners of your file or directory.

Comment: You're right. How does one change it? I would like the owner/group to be the same as the user/group of the user.

Comment: @David, just add your ftp user to your server group (www-data).

Comment: Do you have a second to chat?

Comment: @David, yup http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25641/room-for-question-aws-ec2-vsftpd-shows-file-directory-owner-as-number-48